# Non arithmetic, non geometric series starting with 4 and 8.

Tags: sequences-and-series

My son (7th grade) had this homework problem last night:

Come up with a function for a non arithmetic, non geometric series starting with 4 and 8.

In his math book they define a series as a function $F(n)$ with $n=1,2,3,4,...$

He'd been out sick, and I wasn't sure what process he was supposed to go through to solve it, but I went with a system of equations, where we would have one more unknown than equations.

I'll include my solution below.

Is there a more straightforward way for an algebra I student?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start with $F(1) = 4$ and $F(2) = 8$.  Quadratic solutions are neither arithmetic nor geometric, so we also start with $ax^2+bx+c$.

$F(1) = a(1^2) + b(1) + c = 4$

$F(2) = a(2^2) + b(2) + c = 8$

Equals:

$1a + 1b + c = 4$

$4a + 2b + c = 8$

Subtract twice the first from the second:

$2a + 0b - c = 0 \to a = c/2$

Substituting back,

$b = 4-3c/2$

I then explained there were an infinite number of c's to choose from, but asked him to think of any c that would give integer answers when divided by two.  So we picked 2.

$a = 1, b = 1 \to F(x) = x^2 + x + 2$

Is there a better more intuitive way of achieving this answer -- particularly for a beginning algebra student?

Comment: If by arithmetic you mean linear then your answer is definitely one of the most intuitive.

Comment: Your approach seems simple and sound.
I can suggest two very easy sequences, among the infinite possibilities.
The first one is a Fibonacci-like sequence. $F(1)=4$, $F(2)=8$, and $F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)$. So the series is $4$, $8$, $12$, $20$, $32$, $52$, ...
The second one is defined as $F(1)=4$, and $F(n)$ is the digital reverse of $2 F(n-1)$. Here the sequence is $4$, $8$, $61$ (the reverse of $16$), $221$ (the reverse of $2\cdot61=122$, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The squares $1,4,9,16,25\cdots$ are forming a non-arithmetic, non-geometric sequence.

If we can map $1$ to $4$ and $4$ to $8$, we are done. The linear relation

$$y=(8-4)\frac{x-1}{4-1}+4$$ achieves that.

Hence,

$$f_n=\frac{4n^2+8}3.$$

---

Alternatively, the factorials form a non-arithmetic, non-geometric sequence.

Now, we need to map $1!=1$ to $4$ and $2!=2$ to $8$, and get

$$f_n=4n!$$

---

Alternatively, let us combine the arithmetic series $1,2,3,4\cdots$ with an appropriate geometric series: the first two terms need to be $4-1=3$ and $8-2=6$, hence

$$f_n=n+3\cdot2^{n-1}.$$

And with the double arithmetic series,

$$f_n=2n+2^n,$$ which might be what the teacher expected most.

---

Alternatively, start from the first two terms and create the corresponding arithmetic or geometric series, $4n$ or $2^{n+1}$, and perturb it by a function that vanishes for $n=1$ and $n=2$:

$$f_n=4n+(n-1)(n-2)=n^2+n+2,$$ (like you found) or $$f_n=2^{n+1}+(n-1)(n-2).$$

---

And finally, for the lazy ones,

$$f_1=4,\\f_2=8,\\f_n=0.$$

Comment: These seem out of reach for a 7th grader.