# Getting equation from non-arithmetic and non-geometric sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Before I go into my question, I have checked out
[Non arithmetic, non geometric series starting with 4 and 8.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711835/non-arithmetic-non-geometric-series-starting-with-4-and-8), however I still cannot find a way to solve one.

Currently, lets start with the equation:
$3n + 2^n$

The sequence will look like this:
$5, 10, 17, 28, 47$

I've tried several ways like looking at the differences of the numbers, however $+5, +7, +11, +19$ doesn't give all that much detail. Sure there is $3 + 2^n$, but that is only for the difference. I can't find any relevance between that and the regular sequence.

I've tried other equations like $2n + 3^n$, and $2n + 2^n$, but to no avail.

Comment: `looking at the differences of the numbers` Take the differences one more time and you get $2, 4, 8$ which is easily recognizable. That said, there is no unique answer to the question of determining a formula given the first few terms of a sequence. For example, the polynomial $\,(x^4 - 6 x^3 + 23 x^2 + 18 x + 24) / 12\,$ takes the same first five values $5,10,17,28,47$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I suggest The Book of Numbers by Conway and Guy. They (briefly) discuss methods for hybrid sequences.